# How to add a div in map every 4 iterations?

Tags: reactjs, loops

I want to add the div below every 4 iterations.

```
<div className="clearBoth"></div>
```

How to accomplish this?

```
        {portfolio?.map((portf, index) => (
          
            <Item
                original={require('../img/' + folder + '/' +
                portf.src)}
                thumbnail={require('../img/' + folder + '/' +
                portf.src)}
                >
                {({ ref, open }) => (
                    <img ref={ref} onClick={open} src={require('../img/' + folder + '/' +
                    portf.src)} className={'associatedMedia' + index } />
                )}
            </Item>

        ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `<div>` is to be added after every 4 `Item`, perhaps try:

```
// React might need to be imported

{
  portfolio?.map((portf, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <Item
        original={require("../img/" + folder + "/" + portf.src)}
        thumbnail={require("../img/" + folder + "/" + portf.src)}
      >
        {({ ref, open }) => (
          <img
            ref={ref}
            onClick={open}
            src={require("../img/" + folder + "/" + portf.src)}
            className={"associatedMedia" + index}
          />
        )}
      </Item>
      {index !== 0 && (index + 1) % 4 === 0 && (
        <div className="clearBoth"></div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  ))
}
```

Comment: The first 4 div are correct it adds the right div, after the next 3 div it adds the div which is not correct. Thanks John

Comment: @BrianMillot My bad, I should have tested the condition. Updated it and hope that it improves. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted my previous answer because I don't think you should be adding a `<div>` here. It looks like you're just trying to break rows into sets of 4 (or something similar), and it's better to do that with CSS.

**You could use CSS grid**:

```css
.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, calc(25% - 8px));
  gap: 8px;
}

.items > * {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: slateblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

**Or CSS flexbox:**

```css
.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
}

.items > * {
  flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 8px);
  background: slateblue;
  padding: 1em 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

**Or nth-child with `::after`, etc. etc.:**

(The grid and flexbox solutions will be easier to deal with, but you might have reasons for going this route. Note that you could use nth-child with the suggestions above if you want them to have a different treatment.)

```css
.items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.items > * {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background: slateblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  display: inline-block;
}

.items > :nth-child(4n) {
  background: red;
}

.items > :nth-child(4n)::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg,  slateblue, red);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(22px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```